# MS Access query returns no results

Tags: sql, ms-access

In MS Access 2019 I have a *clients* table with hundreds of records and clients with birthdates from 1940 and later. When I use the following query, I get no results. The problem seems to be the where clause. I use the same function to calculate the *birthyear*, which works, but when I add that same function in a *where* clause I get no results.

```
select id, lastname, birthdate, 
    CInt(Left([birthdate],4)) as birthyear
from clients
where CInt(Left([birthdate],4)) < 1980
```

OUTPUT

```
#Name? #Name? #Name? #Name?
```

I write my queries directly in SQL, do not use the Access wizard. So this is similar to T-SQL I guess.

*Birthdate* is a text field, and when I use the *DateValue()* function, something similar happens. That's why I used a substring with the *birthyear* only, casting it to Int. For some reason I cannot compare it to another integer.

What am I missing here?

---

**Update**

When I use a subquery (or view but that is not possible in Access) and filter out records with empty birthdates, I can then execute the following query without errors:

```
select * from 
(
    select id, lastname, birthdate from clients
    where lcase(birthdate&"") not in ("","null") 
)
where CInt(Left([birthdate],4)) < 1980
```

(Yes, NULL values are exported as "NULL" here!)

Comment: Your SQL works for me on a basic set of data. However, if I enter text such as "kyh" into the birthdate field, I get the same error as you, so I suspect that there is an issue with your data. Also, note that `name` is a reserved word in Access, so you should look at renaming it if possible.

Comment: Thanks. I simplified the query a bit, but "name" is not actually in the query. I've changed it to lastname here. The data in this table is a mess, but the birthdate field is actually OK. To be sure I'm going to check the data and come back later with a reply.

Comment: Please show us the table details in a screenshot focused on the `birthdate` field. Even include some example values of this field. Unless we take your word for it!

Comment: @Applecore, you got it right. See my update. If you want the points, make it an answer. Otherwise I'll approve the answer of Gustav.

Comment: Mark the answer from @Gustav as correct. All I did was suggest what the issue was, without actually giving a proper solution to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably, you have some *Null* values. Try:

```
CInt(Nz(Left([birthdate],4))) As birthyear
```

Or validate the records and correct those failing:

```sql
Select * From Clients
Where Not IsDate(birthdate)
```